# Cannot turn off sampling of application insights

Tags: azure, sampling, azure-appservice, appinsights

I have a DotNet 6 application ASP.NET Web API application that is running as an App Service in Azure.

I do not have fixed sampling enabled. I also do not have applicationinsights.json file in my application.

I have code to disable Adaptive Sampling in the ConfigureServices method. The code snippet is below:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]))
            {
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
                {
                    if (webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        options.DeveloperMode = true;
                        options.EnableDebugLogger = false;
                    }
                    options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
                    options.InstrumentationKey = configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
                });
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<FilterProcessor>();
                services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, NopContextInitializer>();
            }
```

My Azure settings for application insights is as follows for ingestion sampling[image]

I continue to see sampling happening when I run the below query:

```
union requests,dependencies,pageViews,browserTimings,exceptions,traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType
```

My application was a .NET Core 3.1 a few weeks back and could not get sampling to be turned off. Even after upgrading to DotNet 6, I am not able to turn off sampling.

Any pointers on why this may be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

> I also do not have applicationinsights.json file in my application.

When we add `Application Insights Telemetry` from Visual Studio => Project Root Folder, by default `ApplicationInsights.config` used to be generated automatically.

[image]

I have Added `Application Insights Telemetry` from Project Root Folder, even I didn't find `ApplicationInsights.config` added in the application.

There might be some latest changes in Adding the `ApplicationInsights Telemetry`.

We can disable sampling from either `ApplicationInsights.config` or from `code`.

As we don't have `ApplicationInsights.config` file, will try to disable the sampling from Code.

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling?tabs=net-core-new#types-of-sampling),

> Only ASP.NET server-side telemetry currently supports adaptive sampling.

In `Program.cs`, add the below lines of code

```cs
var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false; 
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

- This code works only for the `Production Environment`(Deployed Application).

***For .NET Core 6***

***My Program.cs***

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***My appsettings.json file***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=********;IngestionEndpoint=https://****.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false
  }
}
```

- Re-deploy the App, Access the URL and check the traces/Logs.

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling?tabs=net-core-new#turning-off-adaptive-sampling)

Comment: Hi Harshitha. Thanks for your response. I have application insights adaptive sampling set to false using the code. Inspite of having it set to false, I do see sampling happening in the azure logs. I have already looked at the microsoft documentation before I posted in stack overflow. Is your response based on microsoft documentation or do you have a asp.net core web api application deployed with application insights sampling turned off  ?